Skipping zero multiplications in CNN inference
I have a pre-trained CNN model on MNIST and each time load the trained weights and biases to run inference. Is there any way to skip zero operations in the conv and fc layers in only inference phase (I dont want to retrain it so it doesnt need backpropagate)?
As the MNIST images are sparse so I should be expecting to have much less execution time when skipping zero operations. The optimality of work is not that much important for me, only I want to see how much execution time differs in different rate of zeros in input.
I tried some repositories for sprase convolution but they are considering you retrain the model after it. I was expecting to find a simple change in Pytorch code that just skips the zero operations. Also tried to find a way to change the C++ codebase of Pytorch however I couldnt figure it out.

What do you mean by "zero operations"? Are you setting weights in the model to zero?

Why would you think if x !=0: x*y else 0 is faster than x*y?

No. Actually, I am using the pre-trained weights and biases. And the architecture of the model is the same as the pre-trained model. I mean, in input sparse images like MNIST the majority of the input consists of zeros, I want to skip zero multiplications in conv and linear layer, which should be much more optimized. Please let me know if you need more explanation. @Karl

I first tried your mentioned code, but as you said, it's not faster. So I was looking for a way more faster approach. For example, the multiplication be operated on only the indices of non-zero values. But couldn't find a way for it in Pytorch. @CJR

What you're asking for isn't possible. Read more on how GPUs work. The input is broken up into grids/blocks and farmed out to parallel instances of the compute kernel. The GPU doesn't have the ability to selectively include/exclude parts of the input. Each call of the kernel does the same computations, accesses the same number of memory addresses, etc. Furthermore, even if you could do this, it would only impact the first layer of the model where you operate directly on the sparse inputs. That is a fraction of your total inference time

Thank you for your answer. Actually, I want the code to be run on the CPU, that's why we are able to selectively operate the multiplication on non-zero values. Also, once we do this, the activation zeros between layers are omitted which is a considerable decrease in exe time.

There is no way to skip all the 0s unless you restructure your data in a sparse format and use one of the sparse matrix multiplication routines (which are not currently well-implemented in pytorch but do exist in sparseBLAS)
